# Getting an entry in a List of lists in python

Tags: python

I have a large .txt file of data. I am having trouble getting just a single line of data from the lists of lists. Instead I am getting the column instead of an entry.

here is the sample data set I have been working with...

```
['6/1/13', '9852', '54946', '47498.85', '220999.39', '26752', '2165', '0', '0']

['6/2/13', '17590', '72536', '70659.35', '291658.75', '28248', '4723', '4723', '289']

['6/3/13', '8599', '81135', '31547.41', '323206.16', '29611', '1160', '1160', '221']

['6/4/13', '17589', '98724', '106170.69', '429376.85', '31090', '2922', '2922', '394']
```

Below is the code I have been attempting with...

```
file = open("blahblah.txt","r")
data = []
for line in file:
    parts = line.strip().split()
    data.append(parts)
    print parts [0]
```

Below is the output that I get when i input this code.

```
6/1/13

6/2/13

6/3/13

6/4/13
```

When i ask for it to print `parts[0]` shouldn't it give just the first line of the list of lists? instead it gives me the entry in the first column of the 4 lists. How can I fix my code that I just get the first line beginning with `['6/1/13']`

Comment: if you want the whole line - don't split it and simply `print line`

Comment: You should include what your file looks like

Answer (score 1):

Look at the below code

```
for line in file:
    parts = line.strip().split()
    data.append(parts)
    print parts [0]
```

Firstly, your code should not work. Even if it works, the `print parts [0]` instruction is executed in every iteration. So you will get first portion of every list.

It is not clear how your file looks like. I assume it is just like your sample data. So the below code works.

```
import re

file = open("example.txt","r")
data = []
for line in file:
    line=re.sub('[\[\],\'\']', ' ', line)
    llist =line.split()
    data.append(llist)

print data[0][0]
```

Output:

```
6/1/13
```

To get the whole line, change the print statement to `print data[0]`

Output:

```
['6/1/13', '9852', '54946', '47498.85', '220999.39', '26752', '2165', '0', '0']
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data is parsable by the csv module, the following code will work:

```
with open(txtpath, mode='r', newline='') as f:
    fReader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')
    for rows in fReader:
        list0fRows.append(rows)
        print rows
```

parts[0] is the first entry in the parts list--I think you want data[0] for the first row. The code in this example will print each row in order.